# How to extract SVG height/width in Java without libraries?

Tags: java, svg, height, width, dimensions

There are multiple ways to extract dimensions of a SVG in javascript or php like getBBox() I am looking similar ways to extract SVG height and width in Java. I am trying to avoid using libraries like batik.

Comment: SVG is XML, just load it and parse it as an XML document.

Comment: Are you asking about the dimensions of the SVG image file, or about the dimensions of particular objects contained in the image?

Comment: I want dimension of the SVG image file